# spawn ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, error-handling, imagemagick, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload stuff to amazon s3 with the imager module. I keep getting the error message that says,

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

I've already installed imagemagick on my computer, but it keeps saying it's unlinked, could this be the problem? I also tried linking using brew link imagemagick, but it's unable to link for some reason. I'm using OSx. Any fixes?

Thanks.

Comment: ENOENT usually points to not found file. Make sure your paths are relative and correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure the ImageMagick exe is included as part of PATH environment variable.

Comment: for reference, visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-to-debug-any-node-js-child-process-error-spawn-enoent

Comment: I am using windows 10. Which path should I give in the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

Simply works on [**Ubuntu**](http://www.ubuntu.com/):

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```